# Git .gitignore - Ignore Scripts folder in Visual Studio mvc project

Tags: github, gitignore

So I uploaded my mvc project on github, but the problem is there are so many .js files in Scripts/ folder like jquery and jquery ui, that github recognizes this as JavaScript projest. I want it to be c# project.

I tried to add .gitignore pattern to ignore Scripts folder like this:

Scripts/

File: https://github.com/nukec/real-time-chat/blob/master/.gitignore

which I understand it ignores all folders with name Scripts, but it still shows as JavaScript project.

Any tips welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of project is determined automatically by [Github's Linguist gem](https://github.com/github/linguist).
If you want to ignore those scripts on future commits (which you shouldn't do, if they are necessary to your project), your `.gitignore` file should read like this:

```
Chat/Scripts/*
```

It's also worth noting that even if you change this, unless you remove your scripts from the repository, Linguist will still note them when calculating the language used for the project.